# multiple connections to same spreadsheet (gspread)

Tags: python, gspread

Good Morning, this is my first question so please bear with me! I created a system for doing a mock election at my high school that uses a raspberry pi and a touchscreen. The interface is handled through TKInter and the results are then appended to a google sheet using gspread. This allows me to then process the data in a variety of charts and analysis.

The issue I'm running into is that I am using 4 machines. If I take them one at a time they append the data fine. If I do multiple machines at once I SOMETIMES get one just waiting for the other and sometimes only 1 of the 4 is recorded.

Is there a may to better set things up to push multiple appends simultaneously from the different machines? Currently each machine is a mirror of the others. Would it work better if I did a different authorization setup and different JSON file for each machine? Or is there something else that I am missing? The relavaent code to writing to the sheet is below:

```
    #while True:
    # Login if necessary.
    if worksheet is None:
        worksheet = login_open_sheet(GDOCS_OAUTH_JSON, GDOCS_SPREADSHEET_NAME)

    # Append the data in the spreadsheet, including a timestamp
    try:
        worksheet.append_row((datetime.datetime.now(), gender, grade, party, vote))
    except:
        # Error appending data, most likely because credentials are stale.
        # Null out the worksheet so a login is performed at the top of the loop.
        print('Append error, logging in again')
        worksheet = None
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!!

Comment: Multiple processes accessing the same sheet should not cause blocking like this. In fact, I accidentally had a daily cron job on a script that failed to terminate and by the time I discovered it, I had about 5 or 6 identical processes all fighting with each other on 2 second update intervals. That said, I was referencing cells directly, not _appending_ rows. Uploads of single rows are slow. I wonder if it is possible that you get some race condition on the row and the second process is rejected. Can each machine maybe have its own block of cells and an internal counter to know where to upload?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that if you have all four of these machines starting at the same time they will have a relatively similar state for the sheet. However, once a single machine has made a change the state for all the others becomes different from the actual sheet.

Lets say the sheet starts with N rows.

If Machine1 appends 2 rows to the sheet the number of rows then becomes the N + 2.

BUT

Machines 2-4 still think the sheet has N rows!

When any of these N-row machines tries to append to the sheet they will overwrite the data that Machine1 wrote to the sheet, obviously not something you want to happen when you're tallying votes.

You'll either need to find a way to let each machine know when the state of the sheet has changed and refresh its state or have a single point of contact from which all the appends are made.